# gatsby remark images does not display image

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, gatsby-image

I've seen this elsewhere and have tried numerous things but cannot get it to work for me. .md body photos will not display via gatsby-remark-images. I have updated everything to newest versions as well.

**update now shows full config file**

config:

```
const path = require(`path`)

module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: `xxx`,
    description: `xxx`,
    author: `xxx`,
  },
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-remark-images`,
            options: {
              maxWidth: 1500,
              withWebp: true,
              showCaptions: true,
              quality: 100,

            },
    },
    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
    `gatsby-transformer-remark`,

    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `images`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/images`,
      },
    },

    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `markdown-pages`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/markdown-pages`,
      },
    },


    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
    `gatsby-plugin-react-helmet`,
    `gatsby-plugin-styled-components`,


    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-manifest`,
      options: {
        name: `gatsby-starter-default`,
        short_name: `starter`,
        start_url: `/`,
        background_color: `white`,
        theme_color: `white`,
        display: `minimal-ui`,
        icon: `src/images/gatsby-icon.png`, // This path is relative to the root of the site.
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

inside md:

```
![fail](../images/demo/fail.jpeg)
```

Comment: Can you show us your full gatsby-config file?

Comment: just updated, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to use the default syntax for images in markdown, you can specify the `gatsby-images-remark` plugin to within options to `gatsby-transformer-remark` like

```js
{
  resolve: `gatsby-transformer-remark`,
  options: {
    plugins: [
      {
        resolve: `gatsby-remark-images`,
        options: {
          maxWidth: 1500,
          withWebp: true,
          showCaptions: true,
          quality: 100,
        },
      },
    ],
  },
},
```

Check the [gatsby documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/working-with-images-in-markdown/#using-the-transformer-remark-plugin) for more details.

Comment: Ok I set it up like that. Still getting the same result though :(

Comment: Did you clean cache and build again?

Comment: yes. I cleaned and tried develop and build. It shows the caption and the image icon but no image

Comment: by any change is the image width greater than 1500px? If so please set a larger maxWidth

Comment: It is now working. Did not realize photo had to be in same folder as .md file. I was referencing it elsewhere.

Comment: When reading the docs, I completely overlooked the plugin being nested in the options of transformer-remark. Cheers!

Comment: @TrevPennington I don't know if that was a restriction in older versions, but you can reference images from anywhere now. Just be sure to source them using gatsby-source-filesystem.